# ¿Se sigue programando una página "manualmente"?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

Buenas.. 
Mi pregunta es la que indica en el título, mi conocimiento en desarrollo de páginas web es casi nulo...
¿Se siguen haciendo páginas web a mano usando HTML, CSS, JavaScript?
Vale la pena aprender estos lenguajes? O hoy en día se hace todo con wordpress, wix y similares?
Hay alguna ventaja en hacer una página web sin uno de estos creadores de plantillas online?
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy amplia y se basa principalmente en opiniones, por lo que puede acabar cerrada. Te recomiendo que te pases por el Centro de Ayuda y leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 1. _¿Se siguen haciendo páginas web... usando HTML, CSS, JavaScript?_ Para responder te permitiré que visites una [página que quizá nunca hayas visitado](https://www.w3.org/History/19921103-hypertext/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html) y cualquiera puede hacer una página así, que use solamente HTML. 2. _¿Vale la pena aprender estos lenguajes?_ Todo aprendizaje que no sea dañino es bueno, y aprender es mejor que pasarse la vida viendo vídeos de Youtube, o en los vídeo juegos o en otras cosas 3. _se hace todo con wordpress o..._ No. Hasta WP usa PHP, JS, CSS. 4. _alguna ventaja...?_ depende de ti.

Comment: Los frameworks están muy bien pero no te enseñan a programar. Si solamente quieres hacer una página web, sin enfocarte en nada más, utiliza un buen framework. Si lo que quieres es aprender a programar a la vez, te recomiendo empezar por los lenguajes base (aunque CSS y HTML no sean lenguajes de programación). Esto no quiere decir que no uses frameworks (que te facilitan mucho la vida) si no que si sabes las bases después es mucho más fácil adaptarse a cualquier plataforma ;)